# How to export 3d delaunay triangle mesh with python?

Tags: python, 3d, mesh

I want to use scipy.spatial.delaunay get the triangle mesh from the 3d point cloud. And i use trimesh to save the triangle mesh as .ply form. But the result seems bad. All points play roles as vertices, so it works slowly and bad... how can i get a better mesh output with this delaunay method?

Code:

```
#pcd is 3d point cloud 
tri = Delaunay(pcd)   
#faces
f = tri.simplices
# Mesh
mesh = trimesh.Trimesh(vertices=pos_combine, faces=f)
# show mesh and export it
mesh.show()
mesh.export(file_obj="mesh.ply")
```

Answer (score -1):

I write [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio/) for this. Just do

```py
import meshio

meshio.Mesh(pcd, {"triangles": tri.simplices}).write("out.ply")
```

should do the job.

Comment: Hi @Nico Schlömer, tanks for your answer.  i've tried with 'meshio', hier the tri.simplices is an array(n,4), so i used meshio.Mesh(pcd, {"quad": tri.simplices}).write("out.ply").  But the same issue like above, all points in pcd work as vertices, and the output ply file seems like a whole cube. My pcd contains building, tree,etc. I want them to be seperated.